# Java - Ignore delimiter in String

Tags: java

I have a string using the pipe symbol "| as the delimiter. However, the string data also *contains* the pipe symbol. Is there a way to ignore this?

Example:

```
name|address|age

John|123 Wood Road|Street, London|25
```

Therefore when I do this -

```
text.split("\\|")
```

gives me:

```
John

123 Wood Road

Street, London

25
```

I am expecting this:

```
John

123 Wood Road|Street, London

25
```

Comment: As a human being, I couldn't tell the difference between the delimiter and the regular bar. Synatically, both are directly surrounded by characters. How would you propose to tell the difference even to just a human?

Comment: Will it be always like this ? (I mean the separator within the field address)

Comment: Can you perhaps use a different delimiter?

Comment: Alternatively, is it always the nth pipe character you encounter?

Comment: This is a possibility. Users are free to use any characters on their keyboard. One option I have is to use a different delimiter. But at the same time was wondering if this can be handled in any way.

Comment: how did pipe came in your content ?

Comment: Akhil - User entered the pipe symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.split()` can't differentiate between different occurrences of the same symbol.  You'll have to put in place some rules, either in code or in a regex.  Based on your data, I'm guessing that while you say that pipe can occur within the string data, it really can't occur in name or age, so you could do something like this:

```
String[] results = text.split("\\|")

String name = results[0];
String age = results[results.length - 1]

String address = results[1];
for (int i = 2; i < results.length-1; i++) {
    address = address + "|" + results[i];
}
```

Comment: what if String text = "John|123 Wood Road|Street|State, London|25"; then you again need to change your pharser.

Comment: @AkhilDev How so?  Everything between the first and last pipe is assumed to be the address, and the loop takes care of putting it back together.

Comment: Thanks Sharakan. Will give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

> ***However, the string data also contains the pipe symbol. Is there a way to ignore this?***

This is the wrong way of solving it.

If the user enters name, address and age, you should **sanitize them before storing them**.

So how would you sanitize the user input in this case. Well, you would typically escape any user-entered pipe character with a backslash (before concatenating the final string), so instead of storing

```
John|123 Wood Road|Street, London|25
```

you would store

```
John|123 Wood Road\|Street, London|25
```

This way you can always get back what the user entered, by

1. Splitting on un-escaped pipe characters
2. Unescaping each part.

I do however encourage you to use a library for this, such as OpenCSV.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to use a different delimiter.

Although this is not fool proof, as you may encounter the new delimiter as a valid character in one of your parts (name, address, or age).

My better suggestion is to incorporate some sort of escape character to not treat the pipe as a delimiting pipe when it is encountered. (Perhaps a `\`???)

I imagine you are familiar with the concept of escape characters, as you are using them in the regex which you provide to `String.split()`.

> "John|123 Wood Road\|Street, London|25"

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String text = "John|123 Wood Road|Street, London|25";

int first = text.indexOf("|");
int last = text.lastIndexOf("|");

String name = text.substring(0, first);
String age = text.substring(last + 1);
String address = text.substring(first + 1, last);

System.out.println(name);
System.out.println(address);
System.out.println(age);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
John
123 Wood Road|Street, London
25
```

---

More general solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String text = "John|123 Wood Road|Street, London|25";
    for(String s : getArray(text, 0, 1, 0)) System.out.println(s);
}

public static String[] getArray(String text, int... pipeCount)
{
    String[] arr = text.split("\\|");
    String[] result = new String[3];

    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = "";
        for(int j = 0; j <= pipeCount[i]; j++) result[i] += arr[counter++];
    }
    return result;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
John
123 Wood Road|Street, London
25
```

Answer (score 1):

- In general you can't have anything that is part of data as delimiter. How can you differentiate a delimiter from data if they are same character? The way to go around this is using something uncommon as a delimiter like double pipe `||` or some other pattern that is less probable to be present in data.
- If possible, you can use other data formats like XML, JSON, CSV etc. This is far better solution than the previous one as this will always work.
- In this particular case if you are sure that only address can contain `|` but name and age can't contain `|` then you can split with `|`, take first one as name, last one as age and all parts between them as address. If there are more than one parts between them then address contains `|`. You can then join middle parts with `|` knowing that they are part of address. But this is not a good solution as this won't work if `|` is allowed in first and last fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the user input in some way. For example, if `|` is your delimiter, and your data contains one, change it to something like `%p` (p for pipe!). But then you'll also have to escape all `%`, too. Do this when you serialize your data, and then undo it when you deserialize it.