# How to escape delimiter in data?

Tags: java

I have a list of titles that I want to save as a `String`:
- `title1`
- `title2`
- `title|3`

Now, I want to save this as a single line `String` delimited by `|`, which would mean it ends up like this: `title1|title2|title|3`.

But now, when I split the `String`:

```
String input = "title1|title2|title|3";
String[] splittedInput = input.split("\\|");
```

`splittedInput` will be the following array: `{"title1", "title2", "title", "3"}`.

Obviously, this is not what I want, I want the third entry of the array to be `title|3`.

Now my question: how do I correctly escape the `|` in the titles so that when I split the `String` I end up with the correct array of three titles, instead of 4?

---

@Gábor Bakos

Running this code snippet:

```
String input = "title1|title2|title\\|3";
String[] split = input.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|");

for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    split[i] = split[i].replace("\\\\(?=\\|)", "");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

I get this output: `[title1, title2, title\|3]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using a CSV parser will make your troubles go away

Comment: How would the CSV parser do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Ignore delimiter in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040764/java-ignore-delimiter-in-string)

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount Regarding your edit: it should be `replaceAll` as `replace` replaces literally, not matching regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use anything. For example with `\`:

```
 "title1|title2|title\\|3".split("(?<!\\\\)\\|").map(_.replaceAll("\\\\(?=\\|)", "")) //Scala syntax
```

Resulting:

```
  Array(title1, title2, title|3)
```

The final mapping is required to remove the escaping character too.

`(?<!\\\\)` is [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?=\\|)` is an extra look-ahead for the escaped `|`.

Comment: I want to keep the 3rd title as `title|3` though

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Now what if there is also a `title\4`, how would I handle that considering the `replaceAll`call?

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount That would not match in the updated version: `("title1|title2|title\\|3|title\\4".split("(?<!\\\\)\\|")).map(_.replaceAll("\\\\(?=\\|)", ""))` `Array(title1, title2, title|3, title\4)`

Comment: Okay that does not work in comments, edited my post.

Comment: `replace` expects a simple charsequence, not a regexp, while `replaceAll` uses regex

Answer (score 2):

Well if you use a TSV format the chosen separator **must never be left unescaped in the data**.

You could simply escape your data (for ex, `title1|title2|title\|3`) and you would then split on `(?<!\\)|` (negative lookbehind).

In Java, it gives:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // prints out [title1, title2, title|3, title|4]
    System.out.println(parsePipeSeparated("title1|title2|title\\|3|title\\|4"));
}

private static List<String> parsePipeSeparated(String input) {
    return Stream.of(input.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|"))
                 .map(escapedText -> escapedText.replace("\\|", "|"))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another separator, for instance "title1,title2,title|3", instead of "title1|title2|title|3". And then split(",")

Comment: This does answer my question, but I want a solution where it works with any character, as I never know what character would appear in the titles

Comment: Sure, but then the same problem would arise for commas. The real solution is to have escaping.